# PyWinAuto set_text() function not available

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am using `PyWinAuto` on a Simulator program. It has buttons and labels and text boxes where information can be added. I found the name of the particular textbox/QWidget, "GPS Position ChQWidget3" with `.print_control_identifiers()`. When I try using `dlg.GPSPositionChQwidget3` or `dlg.['GPS Position ChQWidget3']` both return a object of type `WindowSpecification`. This object does not have the `set_text()` function although it does have `click()`, `double_click_input()`, `type_keys()`.

**How do I access the Textbox/QWidget in a different way so I can use the `set_text()` function?**

Although I am able to get around using `set_text()` with the double click and type_keys it is less than ideal because it moves the mouse and sets focus to the textbox which is annoying. I have to double click twice because the value in the field is a double and the double click only take one side of the decimal point. I would prefer the program to run in the background and not move the mouse or focus.

Here is my code sample.

````
import pywinauto
auto = pywinauto.application.Application(backend="win32")  #uia or win32
sim = auto.connect(title_re="Simulator - ")
handles = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title_re="Simulator - ")
dlg = sim.window(handle=handles[0])
dlg.print_control_identifiers()

dlg['GPS Position ChQWidget3']
# outputs -> <pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification object at 0x00000124647C23B0>
dlg['GPS Position ChQWidget3'].double_click_input()
# Highlights the text in the textbox.
dlg['GPS Position ChQWidget3'].type_keys(" ",with_spaces=True)
# Deletes selected text and replaces it with " "
dlg['GPS Position ChQWidget3'].click()
# Moves cursor and focus to the textbox this works.''' 
dlg['GPS Position ChQWidget3'].type_keys("12.34")
# Writes "12.34" into the textbox where ever the cursor is


dlg['GPS Position ChQWidget3'].set_text("12.34")
# outputs -> AttributeError: Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'set_text' were found (typo?)
#     This does not work and I have tried everything I could find off Stack overflow. 
#     Tried functions send_keys() and keyboard("{BACKSPACE}") both don't work ```
````

Comment: PyWinAuto won't run in the background, try these steps

# Set focus
dlg['GPS Position ChQWidget3'].set_focus()

# Select All
dlg['GPS Position ChQWidget3'].type_keys("^A")

# Delete selected
dlg['GPS Position ChQWidget3'].type_keys("{DEL}")

# Type value
dlg['GPS Position ChQWidget3'].type_keys("12.34")

# Press ENTER
dlg['GPS Position ChQWidget3'].type_keys("{ENTER}")

Comment: @SachinPatole Thanks. I eventually found that out. You can actually tie all the strings together and do it in one type_keys(). Side question if a field is not editable or highlightable and it doesn't come up under print_control_identifiers() is there anyway I can get to that item with pywinauto?

Comment: From my experience, if an item doesn't come up under print_control_identifiers() then you can't get to that item using PyWinAuto... also, you can also try using inspect.exe to see which items are available...

Comment: Some elements you can access which are not part of dump_tree but you can get those. for example iface values, in some non editable fields you can see the text in application but not in dump_tree, you can access such text using `get_values()`, also the function differs for `win32` backend and `uia` backend in your case `set_text()` does not work with `win32` backend but it will work with `uia`.